# Xpath Query to select rows from a table

Tags: xpath

I have a web page which has a table with rows of 2 types, **Recommended Recyclers** and **Trade In Prices**.

I want to select only those rows from the table which are under **Recommended Recyclers** category only.

Here is the link of web page:
http://www.sellmymobile.com/phone/orange-spv-m5000/

I need xpath for this selection.

Comment: Which would be: translate the following into xpath: select all `tr` in `table with id=content` which are preceded by one `tr` with a child `td class="section-head"`, but not more then one (count!). Does that help you on your way?

Comment: Or alternatively if the table varies, all `tr`'s in that `table` which are preceded with a `tr` with a `td class=secion-head`, which `contains` the text `"recommended recyclers"`

Comment: Thanks for translating my question but actually the problem is that I don't have much knowledge of xpaths. I'm a newbie to xpaths so don't know how to translate your solution statement into an xpath.
I would really appreciate if you can post the xpath for what you said in your statement.

Comment: Well, that's a great opportunity to learn it! :)  Can you scrounge up some xpath tutorial, fiddle a bit, and if you don't succeed, share your best effort?  Then we'll take a look at it.

Comment: Here is the xpath I came up with, it's working fine and selecting the exactly those rows which I want:

.//*[@id='results']/tbody/tr[following-sibling::tr/td[@class="section-head" and contains(.,"Trade In Prices")] and preceding-sibling::tr/td[@class="section-head" and contains(.,"Recommended Recyclers")]]

It seems to be very long :P, may be you can suggest a shorter version of this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a xpath mostly according the explanation form Wrikken.

```
"//tr[
      preceding-sibling::tr[td/@class='section-head']
      [1]
      [ contains(td, 'Recommended Recyclers')]
     ][not (td/@class='section-head')]"
```

With small differences:
Looking for all tr where the first presiding tr with "@class='section-head'" contains an td which contains "Recommended Recyclers". But only tr which has not an td with "@class='section-head'".